# PHP Warning: include(): Failed opening

Tags: php

I have this error on my site after I moved it from a shared hosting to a VPS (both with cPanel).

> PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '../../../transporturi/a.php'
>   for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear') in [...]
>   on line 36.

In the other file on line 36 I have included a PHP file, I checked the path and it's there. I also tried to switch PHP version from the WHM from 5.5 to 5.6 to 7.0, but no luck.

Comment: Can you add your tree directory?

Comment: Does the file have the right permissions?

Comment: 1 - Does this file exist at it's expected location; and 2 - Without any info other than a generic warning with no background does this really deserve a upvote yet?

Comment: 1. I already wrote that it is there and yes it has the right pemissions. Also, didn't move any folder, just zipped the old ones and put them on the same domain, same structure.

Comment: some ideas to try. 1) include a known file that is in the same dir as the original (ie no need for '..'). 2) include the file by absolute filename (ie starting with '/'). 3) check for differences in the include_path between this hosting and the previous one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path is relative to the file **that received the request**, so you can use the PHP  **DIR** [magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) to know what is your current directory:

```
echo(__DIR__);
```

and then form the absolute path relative to your file as below.

```
include(__DIR__ . '../../../transporturi/a.php');
```

Now it depends on your directory structure and the location of both the included file and the one where its included.

Comment: Yeah... simple as that :) Sometimes I really mess up. Thank you so much and thanks not being just another one that thinks he knows stuff, but actually knows nothing.